# Zero gets omitted while inserting by Hibernate query?

Tags: sql, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate.I am passing a value 0261 to be inserted by Hibernate query but when i check the DB, 261 gets inserted.

Comment: You need to post the structure of the table. If the column is declared as numeric, there is no way to keep the leading 0.

Comment: Yes i checked its integer. Changed it to varchar, now its working thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then pass that value as a string instead of number